Shopify GraphQL API: Create a Basic Product and Set the Price with 2024-10 API version
Old versions of the Shopify GraphQL productCreate mutation seemingly offered a variants field where you could set the price of the product you were creating.
The latest version as of writing this (2024-10) does not seem to have this option.
Is there a way to create a basic product with only one variant (or no variants!) and set a price in a single operation?
And if it must be done in two operations? What is the correct second mutation?

productVariantsBulkCreate seems like a likely option, but the "bulk" word in the name makes me think there is probably a simpler mutation. But that seems to be the only mutation that lets you create a price.


First, create a product for ID, then add a variant with price, though productVariantsBulkCreate is preferred even for single variants.

if you add this as an answer and not just a comment, I can mark it as an accepted answer.

@CleverPatrick , We need to follow these steps:
First, create a product for ID, then add a variant with price, though productVariantsBulkCreate is preferred even for single variants.
